Limit of $\mathbb{P}(A_n|B_n)$ for $A_n,B_n\rightarrow A,B$
I'm searching for an "exact" proof of the convergence of conditional probability
$\mathbb{P}(A_n|B_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A|B)$
as $A_n,B_n \rightarrow A,B$ and $\mathbb{P}(B),\mathbb{P}(B_n)>0$.
The definition of $A_n \rightarrow A$ would be that $\mathbb{1}_{A_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{1}_A$.
In this sense, for me intuitively showing that it works seems obvious:
$lim \mathbb{P}(A_n|B_n)= lim \frac{\mathbb{P}(A_n\cap B_n)}{\mathbb{P}(B_n)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$
i.e. since both probabilities obviously converge, but I'm wondering about a more rigorous logical chain also having an eye on the fact that it's the limit of the fraction of the two functions.
Any help is appreciated!

Consider some sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of sets converging to a set $S$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, since $S_n\rightarrow S$, we have that there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\vert 1_{S_n} - 1_{S_{}}\vert < \epsilon$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\geq N$. Now take expectations: $$\mathbb E\vert 1_{S_n} - 1_{S_{}}\vert < \epsilon$$ and recall that $$\vert \mathbb P(S_n) - \mathbb P(S)\vert = \vert \mathbb E1_{S_n} - \mathbb E1_{S_{}}\vert = \vert\mathbb E[1_{S_n} - 1_{S_{}}]\vert\leq \mathbb E\vert 1_{S_n} - 1_{S_{}}\vert.$$ Thus, $S_n\rightarrow S$ implies $\mathbb P(S_n)\rightarrow \mathbb P(S)$.
By assumption, $A_n\rightarrow A$ and therefore $\mathbb P(A_n) \rightarrow \mathbb P(A)$. Similarily, we have that $\mathbb P(B_n)\rightarrow \mathbb P(B)$. Since $A_n\rightarrow A$ and $B_n\rightarrow B$, and $1_{A_n\cap B_n} = 1_{A_n}\cdot 1_{B_n}$, it follows from continuity of the limit that $1_{A_n\cap B_n}\rightarrow 1_{A_{}\cap B_{}}$. Thus, $\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)\rightarrow \mathbb P(A\cap B)$. Finally, continuity of the limit (and the fact that $\mathbb P(B_n), \mathbb P(B)>0$) yields $$\mathbb P(A|B) := \frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)} = \frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb P(B_n)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)}{\mathbb P(B_n)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb P(A_n|B_n).$$

Thanks a lot for the effort, but can I simply pull the limit or of the fraction? That’s basically what I was wondering about.

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a convergent sequence. Then $\lim_n f(Z_n) = f(\lim_n Z_n)$. Take $f(x,y) = x/y$ and $Z_n = (X_n, Y_n)$. It only remains to clarify whether $\lim_n (X_n,Y_n) = (\lim_n X_n,\lim_n Y_n)$.  But this is true since the coordinate projections $\pi_1(x,y) = x$ and $\pi_2(x,y) = y$ are continuous.

And that holds since I know that P(B) and P(B_n)>0? Thanks for the clarification!

You need $P(B),P(B_n)>0$ for the conditional probability to be well-defined.

I suppose $1_{A_n} \to 1_A$ means $1_{A_n} \to 1_A$ almost surely.  You cannot write convergence of random variable without specifying the type of convergence.
This is a simple application of Dominated Convergence Theorem. Since $1_{A_n} \to 1_A$ and $1_{B_n} \to 1_B$ almost surely we get $1_{A_n} 1_{B_n}\to 1_A1_B$ almost surely Now apply Dominated Convergence Theorem to see that $\int 1_{A_n} 1_{B_n} dP \to \int 1_A1_B$ and $\int 1_{B_n} \to \int 1_B$.
